# How to move Magento Coupon Block from the Cart page to the one page checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, onepage-checkout, coupon

I would like to move the coupon code block from the cart page to the checkout page if this is possible or add an extra block on to the onepage checkout
I am using CE 1.7.

Comment: have you try something

Comment: Nope,  I know how to remove the block from the cart but not add it to the checkout page

Comment: are you  magento default onepage checkout or any extension ?

Comment: It is the default magento onepage checkout. Thanks Mike

Comment: on which step are you want?

Comment: After the review step if possible?

Comment: yes poosiable....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is free extension available for that

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/add-coupon-code-from-your-checkout-process.html

https://www.apptha.com/blog/add-discount-coupon-in-magento-one-page-checkout-with-and-without-coding/

> Note::I am not promoting this extension ,,i have placed here due to
>   free extension

Answer (score 1):

As you want to `apply the coupon on review step` then you need to ap`ply coupon and update review content using ajax`.

**Step1:** First `override` the controller `Onepagecontroller.php` using below link

1. [Making edits to core controllers OnepageController.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/making-edits-to-core-controllers-onepagecontroller-php)
2. [How to override a controller in Magento](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/)

**Step2:**  Then on the override controller `Amit_CustomCheckout_OnepageController` add a function `applycouponAction`,in where you have send the ajax `request to apply coupon` and return `update content of review step`.

```
<?php 
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Checkout").DS."IndexController.php";
class Amit_CustomCheckout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    public function applycouponAction(){        /**
         * No reason continue with empty shopping cart
         */
        if (!$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
                    $result['error']=true;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('No item in cart.');
         $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

            return;
        }

        $couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
            $couponCode = '';
        }
        $oldCouponCode = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getCouponCode();

        if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
                    $result['error']=true;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
         $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            return;
        }

        try {
            $codeLength = strlen($couponCode);
            $isCodeLengthValid = $codeLength && $codeLength <= Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart::COUPON_CODE_MAX_LENGTH;

            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();

            $result=array();

            if ($codeLength) {
                if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                    $result['error']=false;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
                    $result['html']=$this->_getReviewHtml();
                } else {
                    $result['error']=true;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
                }
            } else {

                    $result['error']=false;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code was canceled.');
                    $result['html']=$this->_getReviewHtml();

            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
                    $result['error']=true;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.');

        } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result['error']=true;
                    $result['message']=$this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.');
                    Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

}
}
```

In this code,  i have `return json data with a flag field name errooe` .html return contend of handler `checkout_onepage_review` and check this h`andler file at checkout.xml`

Then basic on this logic you need to update content